# How to have query string parameter(s) and field name(s) different

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, binding

I have a controller which will have 3 query strings.

Instead of having 3 fields in controller, I am defining them in class.

```
public class PassengerInformation{
   String travellerAddress;
   String travellerAge;
   String travellerName;
}
```

Now in controller , I am able to accept them

```
@GetMapping("/passenger-info)
public TravelInformation getPassengerInfo(PassengerInformation info){
//Call a service
}
```

Now, this works as expected, if I pass the query string as is. eg: `/passenger-info?travellerAge=21`.

But, How do I accept the query parameter names different to it's corresponding fieldName.

I should be able to call it as below:
`/passenger-info?traveller_age=21&traveller_name=JohnWick&traveller_address=ST`.

Comment: You don't. At least not by default, you could make this work by writing your own `WebDataBinder` along the same lines as the `BeanWrapperRowMapper` in SQL. But there is currently no default way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following constructor to your class

```
public class PassengerInformation{
       String travellerAddress;
       String travellerAge;
       String travellerName;
    
       @ConstructorProperties({"traveller_address", "traveller_age", "traveller_name"})
       public PassengerInformation(String travellerAddress, String travellerAge, String travellerName) {
                this.travellerAddress = travellerAddress;
                ...
       }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do by the default features without any customisation is to use  `@ConstructorProperties` :

```java
public class PassengerInformation {
    String travellerAddress;
    String travellerAge;
    String travellerName;
    
    @ConstructorProperties({ "traveller_address", "traveller_age", "traveller_name" })
    public PassengerInformation(String travellerAddress, String travellerAge, String travellerName) {
        this.travellerAddress = travellerAddress;
        this.travellerAge = travellerAge;
        this.travellerName = travellerName;

    }
}
```

This behaviour is mentioned at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) as follows :

> The `@ModelAttribute` parameter instance (i.e `PassengerInformation`)
> is sourced in one of the following ways:
>
> - Retrieved from the model where it may have been added by a
>   @ModelAttribute method.
> - Retrieved from the HTTP session if the model attribute was listed in
>   the class-level @SessionAttributes annotation.
> - Obtained through a Converter where the model attribute name matches
>   the name of a request value such as a path variable or a request
>   parameter (see next example).
> - Instantiated using its default constructor.
> - Instantiated through a “primary constructor” with arguments that match
>   to Servlet request parameters. Argument names are determined through
>   JavaBeans @ConstructorProperties or through runtime-retained parameter
>   names in the bytecode.

The caveat here is that you need to make sure there are no `default constructor` in the `PassengerInformation` :

```java
public class PassengerInformation {

   public PassengerInformation(){}

}
```